# Simpler way to bind onTap functions to buttons in WeChat mini-program

Tags: javascript, wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I'm creating a simple audio playing app for WeChat.
On the play screen, it has 5 control buttons - prev, fast backward, play/pause, fast forward, and next.
So I created them and binded to each event listening functions.

```
<!-- part of play.wxml -->

<view class="button-group">
    <image class="button" src="../../res/img/control_prev.svg" bindtap="onPrev"></image>
    <image class="button" src="../../res/img/control_fback.svg" bindtap="onFBack"></image>
    <image class="button" src="../../res/img/control_play.svg" bindtap="onPlay"></image>
    <image class="button" src="../../res/img/control_ffor.svg" bindtap="onFFor"></image>
    <image class="button" src="../../res/img/control_next.svg" bindtap="onNext"></image>
</view>
```

On `play.js`, I had to define all those 5 functions.

```
/* part of play.js */

onPrev: (event) => {
    Player.prev()
},
onFBack: (event) => {
    Player.fback()
},
onPlay: (event) => {
    Player.play()
},
onFFor: (event) => {
    Player.ffor()
},
onNext: (event) => {
    Player.next()
},
```

I think there must be a better way to simplify this repeated code.
How can I make them as one function and bind it to multiple buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function for it and pass a id for each button using `data-*` property.

For example,

```html
<image class="button" src="../../res/img/control_prev.svg" bindtap="onTap" data-id="prev"></image>
<image class="button" src="../../res/img/control_fback.svg" bindtap="onTap" data-id="fback"></image>
...
```

```js
onTap: (event) => {
    let id = event.currentTarget.dataset.id
    if (id == "prev")
        Player.prev()
    else if (id == "fback")
        Player.fback()
    ...
```